# Visa free passport with a Schengen entry stamp but no exit stamp

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, passports, passport-stamps

I am a Ghanaian by birth but have Argentine citizenship. In 2015, I first went to Ghana, then went on to France where my passport was stamped.

I spent one month in France,  2 weeks in Germany, 2 weeks in Italy, 2 weeks in Belgium. When I took the bus from Brussels to London, I didn't get an exit stamp. I returned to Argentina from England; my passport was not stamped on exit there either.

I traveled from Argentina to Ghana and on to Turkey, where I am now, and my passport has an entry stamp. I'm planning to take a bus from Turkey to other areas in Europe.

Can I enter the Schengen area without a problem, since I didn't get an exit stamp from any of the Schengen states I visited in 2015 before going to London?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. The UK doesn't issue exit stamps. Did you get an exit stamp when you left the Schengen area?

Comment: Your write up is all over the place. Can you edit it and lay out sequentially and clearly where and where you went and where you did not get stamps. Very confusing.

Comment: Hope my editing now helps @paul

Comment: You didn't get an exit stamp when you took the bus from Brussels to London?

Comment: @zach nah I didn't

Comment: @ Zach nah I was allowed without any stamp

Comment: See the linked question. It's possible that you'll be questioned about it on a future trip, but you can provide evidence that you really left the Schengen area when you said you did. For example, you should have a UK entry stamp in your passport that you can show. You might also carry a copy of the bus ticket or other such proof if you have it.

Comment: Well at least you have proof of entering UK from Brussels, or at least proof of entering Argentina from UK? You're allowed 90 days in Schengen zone so if the time between when you entered France and when you entered Argentina (with a stamp) is 90 days or less that proves you spent less than 90 days in Schengen total and you're fine.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie "when you entered Argentina (with a stamp)" Most countries don't stamp their own passports - however the UK entry stamp should constitute proper evidence

Comment: @ Paul I will find out if only I make the trip again I want to use Greece to Hungary from  turkey  because It is a Schengen state  instead of Bulgaria to Hungary which is short but not schengen also will I be stamp after turkey has already stamped my passport ?

Answer (score 1):

> I returned to Argentina from England; my passport was not stamped on exit there either.

The UK doesn't issue exit stamps

> When I took the bus from Brussels to London, I didn't get an exit stamp.

Ah, the laissez-faire French! In all seriousness, in the future **always** request a stamp if they're trying to break the law (because not stamping you out of laziness is against the law)

> Can I enter the Schengen area without a problem, since I didn't get an exit stamp from any of the Schengen states I visited in 2015 before going to London?

Being that you have a UK entry stamp, you should be fine.